# How do I construct a bar chart "R" with where the x-axis is a set of categories

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am working with a large data set of more than 5400 rows, each row corresponding to an individual. One of the columns refers to the percentage of meetings that each individual attended during the fiscal year. The percentage attendance has the following five values which are listed in a column marked "Attendance Category." These five possible values are "<50%", "50-79%", "80-89%", "90-95%", "95+%". I tried constructing a histogram which would show the relative frequency distribution of the individuals in each one of the five categories. I used the following code:

```
 hist(mydata, main="Distribution in Attendance Category", xlab="Percentage of Meetings Attended", border="blue", las=1, breaks=4 )
```

My error tells me that "x" must be numeric which makes sense. When I tried to encode the column as.numeric it gave me a set of values such as 5, 6, 7, 3 for each row.

How can I  set you a histogram that uses these five values listing percentage range of meetings attended into a histogram. The y-axis would be the number of company employees who attended the percentage of each of these meetings. For example, 2000 company employees (y-axis) would be placed into the "50-79%" category (x-axis).

Comment: What you are describing is a bar chart, not a histogram

Comment: just add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ggplot for added flexibility in your plotting. Using the diamonds data set as a template for your question, consider something like the following:

```
library("ggplot2")
head(diamonds)

ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cut), stat = "bin", color = "blue") + 
  ggtitle("Distribution in Attendance Category") + 
  xlab("Percentage of Meetings Attended")
```

So yours might look something like:

```
ggplot(data = mydata) + 
      geom_bar(aes(x = factor(attendance_category)), stat = "bin", color = "blue") + 
      ggtitle("Distribution in Attendance Category") + 
      xlab("Percentage of Meetings Attended")
```

Note that I made "attendance_category" into a factor. This will let ggplot automatically create one bar per category. To address the comment about bar plots not being the same as histograms: bar plots show categorical data whereas histograms show numerical/continuous data. A histogram is a *type* of bar graph used to show a distribution.

If you would like a more tailored answer, please provide some of your data or an otherwise reproducible example. This will help us answer your question more precisely and help other users understand what's going on.